# An inequality on trace of sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, asymptotics, numerical-linear-algebra, trace

Let $A$ be a stable matrix (that is, $\rho(A) <1$) and $B$ be a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix. Now, if we define
$$
f(N) = \sum_{i=1}^N \mbox{tr} \big((A^{i-1})' B A^{i-1} \big),
$$
can we show that $f(N)$ grows with $\sqrt{N}$ rate?

**My incomplete solution:**
\begin{align}
f(N) &= \sum_{i=1}^N \mbox{tr} \big(B A^{i-1}(A^{i-1})' \big)\leq 
\sum_{i=1}^N \mbox{tr} \big(B \big) \mbox{tr} \big(A^{i-1}(A^{i-1})' \big) \\
& \leq trace \big(B \big) \sum_{i=1}^N  \mbox{tr} \big(A^{i-1}(A^{i-1})' \big) \\
& \leq \mbox{tr} \big(B \big) \sum_{i=1}^N 0.5 \times [ \mbox{tr} \big(A^{i-1} A^{i-1}\big) + \mbox{tr} ((A^{i-1})' (A^{i-1})' ) ] \\
& \leq \mbox{tr} \big(B \big) \sum_{i=1}^N  \mbox{tr} \big(A^{2i-2} \big) 
\end{align}
The first inequality is correct because $B$ and $A^{i-1}(A^{i-1})'$ are both positive semi-definite and the third inequality is correct because $2\mbox{tr}(AB) \leq \mbox{tr}(A^2) + \mbox{tr}(B^2)$. Any idea for how should we continue with $\mbox{tr} \big(A^{2i-2}\big) $?

If we cannot say something when $A$ is a stable matrix, what if we know that $A$ is a strongly stable matrix (that is, $||A|| <1$)?

Comment: In this context, does "stable" mean that the eigenvalues of $A$ satisfy $|\lambda| < 1$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes, I will add this description to the question. Thanks.

Comment: It might help to note the following: if we decompose $B$ as $B = \sum_k x_k x_k^T$, then we can write
$$
f(N) = \sum_{k} \sum_{i=1}^N \|(A^{i-1})'x_k\|^2
$$

Comment: I'm also not exactly sure what "sublinear" means in this context

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I guess it means $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{f(N)}{N} = 0$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $B$ is positive semidefinite, we can write $B = \sum_{k=1}^r x_k x_k^T$ (where $r$ is the rank of $B$). Thus, we have
$$
f(N) = \sum_{k=1}^r \sum_{i=1}^N \|(A^{i-1})'x_k\|^2
$$
Let $C = A'$, and let $\rho$ denote the spectral radius of $C$. Notably, we have $\rho < 1$. For all $x \in \Bbb R^n$, we have
$$
\|C^{i-1}x\| \leq \|C^{i-1}\| \|x\| \leq  \alpha \rho^{i-1} \|x\|
$$
for some $\alpha > 0$.  Thus, we can write
$$
f(N) = \sum_k \sum_i \|C^i x_k\|^2 \leq \sum_k \sum_i \alpha^2 \rho^{2(i-1)} \|x_k\|^2 = \alpha^2 \frac{1 - \rho^{2N}}{1 - \rho} \sum_{k=1}^r \|x_k\|^2
\\ = \alpha^2 \frac{1 - \rho^{2N}}{1 - \rho} \operatorname{trace}(B) \leq \frac{\alpha^2 \operatorname{trace}(B)}{1 - \rho}
$$
So, we have a stronger statement: there is an $M > 0$ such that $f(N) \leq M$ for all $N$.  That is, $f(N)$ is $O(1)$.

Comment: Some minor points: (1) since you are dealing with a submultiplcative norm, you can pull out $\|B\|$ without decomposing $B$; (2) the inequality $\|C^{i-1}\|\|x\|\le\alpha\rho^{i-1}\|x\|$ isn't quite right, e.g. when $\rho=0$. But of course, as $\rho$ is arbitrarily close to some submultiplicative norm and that this norm is equivalent to Frobenius norm, the problem can be rectified easily.

Comment: As @user1551 mentioned, I guess the norm less than spectral radius inequality is not correct. I added my incomplete solution to the question. Any idea how we can continue from there?

Comment: If we assume matrix norm of $C$ is less than 1, then that inequality is fine.

Comment: @user1551 I didn't get your suggestion for handling the issue with that inequality. Can you add more details?

Comment: @user491626 As $\rho<1$, $\|C\|_\triangle<1$ for some submultiplicative matrix norm $\|\cdot\|_\triangle$. Moreover, as all norms are equivalent on a finite-dimensional vector space, $\|\cdot\|\le K\|\cdot\|_\triangle$ for some constant $K>0$. It follows that $$\|C^ix\|\le\|C^i\|\|x\|\le K\|C^i\|_\triangle\|x\|\le K\|C\|_\triangle^i\|x\|$$ and hence $f(N)\le\sum_k\sum_{i=1}^\infty K\|C\|_\triangle^i\|x_k\|^2=\frac{K\|C\|_\triangle^{2}}{1-\|C\|_\triangle^{2}}\sum_k \|C\|_\triangle^{2i}\|x_k\|^2$.

Comment: @user1551 I think they are some typos in your comment but I got what you meant more and less. Is there any reference for your first sentence that if $\rho (A) <1$, there is a sub-multiplicative matrix norm $\| \cdot \|_{\Delta}$ such that $\| A \|_{\Delta}$?

Comment: @user491626 Given any complex square matrix $C$ and any number $\epsilon>0$, there exists a submultiplicative norm $\|\cdot\|_\triangle<\rho(C)+\epsilon$. This is a well-known result, usually proved along Gelfand's formula. I haven't any book at hand, but I am sure that Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* has a proof for it. You may also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand's_formula).